# Как написать регулярное выражение для получения имени переменной в PHP?

Tags: php

Как написать регулярное выражение к

```
$head = <<<EOT
бла
EOT;
```

к `$head = 'бла';` делаю так

```
$content = file_get_contents($article);

preg_match("|head = '(.*)\'\;|Ui", $content, $matches1);
$head = $matches1[1];
```

Comment: вы пытаетесь название переменой получить что ли?

Comment: ну да нужно вывести из переменной

Comment: я написал пример ниже

Comment: так вывезти ИЗ ПЕРЕМЕННОЙ или ИМЯ ПЕРЕМЕННОЙ ?

Answer (score 0):

Для начала - так:

```
$article = <<<EOT
бла
EOT;

//$content = file_get_contents($article);
$content = $article; // Перезапись переменной для примера

preg_match('~.+~u', $content, $matches);
$head = $matches[0];

echo $head; // бла
```